# Linking probability of individual events with probability of combination of those events

Tags: probability, combinations

I have just started learning probability and I am confused with the following.

If a fair coin is tossed 6 times, what is the probability of getting 2 consecutive heads.

I tried solving it using the following method :

The total number of possible out comes is :

(6C0) + (6C1) + (6C2) + (6C3) + (6C4) + (6C5) + (6C6) = 64

Desirable outcomes are

H H T T T T

T H H T T T

T T H H T T

T T T H H T

T T T T H H

= 5 out comes.

So the probability of getting two consecutive heads is 5/64

Can you please clarify the following:

1. Is this answer correct?
2. Is there a permutation/combination formula to find the number of two consectuive anything with out listing it out as I did?
3. Also how do I derive this answer using the fact that the probability of getting a head or tail in a single throw is 1/2 ? That is how do I link the individual probability to find the probability of a combination of event as above?

Comment: H H T T H T is also "desirable...

Comment: @Did Right! So now my first outcome can have 16 possible combination (HHXXXX where X can be any of H or T). Now I am completely lost ... How do I eliminate duplicates in the other combinations? Is there an easier way of calculating this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $k\geqslant1$, let $n_k$ denote the number of words of length $k$ which do not contain HH. Then $n_1=2$ and $n_2=3$. A word of length $k+2$ with no HH is either TU where U is a word of length $k+1$ with no HH, or HTV where V is a word of length $k$ with no HH. Thus, $n_{k+2}=n_{k+1}+n_k$ hence $(n_k)$ is a shift of the Fibonacci sequence, in particular $n_6=21$. There are $2^6=64$ words of length $6$ hence the probability that a word of length $6$ contains HH is $1-\frac{n_6}{64}=\frac{43}{64}$.

Comment: Thanks! I am seeing Fibonacci pattern on a problem for the first time. This is interesting.